# Can I get an compatible version of WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5 for free for testing my source code?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

I'm coding an application for a firm that runs *WAS 8.5.5 - Java IBM SDK 7.0*.

I haven't found a developers version for free. There's a free option for **develop and test** my application with Websphere Application Server 8.5.5? It's important to test the application, so I need a *runtime* version too.

There's a server called '*Liberty Core*' ( [WAS Liberty](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments/) ). Is this server really compatible with WAS 8.5.5? Which version of '*Liberty Core*' is the best to develop for WAS 8.5.5?

Avoiding deadlines of trial versions, if possible.

Comment: First link in google - https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/WAS_traditional_for_Developers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. For traditional WAS, you can obtain a no-charge version for development and testing. This variant is called WebSphere Application Server for Developers, and is available for v9.0 and v8.5.5 of WAS.

It should be noted that the Developer edition is intended for use by individual developers on their workstations. You are not permitted to run a shared/centralized server instance of this product. The [product FAQ](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasdevelopers/faq-wasdevelopers.html) is pretty clear on this:

> **What exactly is the entitlement provided with the no-charge WebSphere
>   Application Server for Developers?**
>
> The entitlement provided with the
>   no-charge WebSphere Application Server for Developers is: For each
>   WebSphere Application Server for Developers license, you are
>   authorized to install each component of the no-charge WebSphere
>   Application Server for Developers on a single machine for use by a
>   single developer for purposes of testing code to confirm that such
>   code functions as designed. You are not authorized to use copies of
>   the no-charge WebSphere Application Server for Developers for the
>   following purposes: testing applications on servers separate from the
>   developer's machine; or simulating production workloads or testing
>   scalability of any code, application or system. The no-charge
>   WebSphere Application Server for Developers cannot be used for to
>   provide runtime support for production applications.

For WebSphere Liberty, a similar version is available, which is called [Liberty Core](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/). This is again a no-charge/no-support edition, but the license allows the use of the server in small-scale test and production environments, which includes shared/centralized instances.

On the development side, you can use the WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools plugin for Eclipse to work with the servers.

WAS Traditional and WAS Liberty are similar in the sense that they offer similar capabilities and compliance to the Java EE platform. Liberty takes the traditional WAS architecture and breaks it down into a pick-and-match model, which allows you to select the features you need. This makes Liberty more flexible, compared to traditional WAS. For a more detailed comparison, see [this article](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/was-classic-or-was-liberty-how-to-choose/).

Comment: Your first paragraph in inaccurate. 2GB restriction is for production usage, not development. Check this - "For each WebSphere Application Server for Developers license, you are authorized to install each component of the no-charge WebSphere Application Server for Developers on a single machine for use by a single developer for purposes of testing code to confirm that such code functions as designed." See details [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasdevelopers/faq-wasdevelopers.html)

Comment: @Gas : Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my answer to reflect the same. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify a bit part of the question ***Is this server really compatible with WAS 8.5.5?***

In case of traditional WAS 8.5.5, if you want to use Liberty as dev platform, you have to stick to Java EE6 features, as tWAS doesn't support Java EE 7 in V8.5.5.x (it supports in v9, so suggest to migrate if you need these).

So best option in case of Liberty to use for tWAS 8.5.5 would be to download just [runtime version](https://developer.ibm.com/assets/wasdev/#asset/runtimes-wlp-runtime) and install `baseBundle` using install utility.

Plain Liberty Core (without additional features installed) will be missing features that are available in tWAS. Check [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_feat.html) for featrues in Liberty Core and others.